# Recommendations for Azure web application

Tags: azure, enterprise-library

I am developing a new web application for the Windows Azure cloud, but have become confused by all the available guidelines, best pratices, storage possibilites, caching and security. I have watched a ton of videos, and read a ton of documentation, but the more I read, the more confusion is added to the layer of decision making. Here is what I what want:

1 - Develop a web application where users can login using a email/password combination. When logging in the user will have a session containing a combination of a UserID+CustomerID. The UserID+CustomerID will be used to display specific data for this user. The application is for law firms, so the security has to be very tight. The application will have 10000+ users, and maybe around 200-500 concurrently. I have read that ASP.NET Sessions should be stored in the Shared Caching service in order for Sessions not to be reset in case of a node upgrade/faulty node. As far as I understand there is 100 transactions per second limit on 128 mb cache - I am not sure this works - If I am getting Session data from the Cache will this count as one transaction?

In an old application I am using code like this (is this approach the right one for Azure, or should I develop some custom Session management system for handling? Any code samples?):

```
    protected void CustomValidatorLogin_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)    
    {
        string result = String.Empty;
        if (DataAccess.User_Logon(this.txtEmail.Text, this.txtPassword.Text, Request.UserHostAddress, Request.UserAgent, ref result)
        {
           args.IsValid = true;
           FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,    this.txtEmail.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Constants.sessionExpires), false, result);
           HttpCookie cookie = null;
           if (cbRemember.Checked)                
           {
              FormsAuthenticationTicket sticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, result, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Constants.sessionExpires), false, result);
              cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName + Constants.cookiePrefix, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(sticket));
              cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
           }
           else
           {
            cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName + Constants.cookiePrefix, string.Empty);
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        }
            Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(result, false);
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

2 - Similar, according to this
    http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/best-practices/security/
    there is a ton of security considerations I should be aware of.
    Could anybody recommend some code samples on how to create login
    functionality taking these best-practices into?

3 -  The system will allow users to save data (upload files) which can later be downloaded, deleted, updated. The files will both be user-specific (UserID), but also customer specific (CustomerID). A user can for example upload a file the only he will have access to (UserID), but he can also upload a file that will be available to the entire organization (the law firm) based on CustomerID. I am confused whether to choose BLOB or Tables and why. In addition what would then be the best practice to implement such functionality.

4 - I am thinking about using Enterprise Library for Data Access Layer - does anybody know a good video walkthrough for newcomers to Azure?

This is a awful lot of questions I know, but still hoping for some expert recommendations.

Cheers.

Comment: Your question is unlikely to get many responses, not because it's a bad question, but because you are actually asking about 10 different questions here. You should close this question and then create a new question for each of the different questions you are asking above.

Comment: Hi Hugh - I hear what you are saying. I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are making some key design decisions for a production application, so I would strongly encourage you to work with an expert and not rely on forum advice alone for something this fundamental.

Regarding item 1 (security), the security best practices article you referenced is a good one but it won’t make your decisions for you. As it points out, there are many ways to handle identity, and Windows Azure doesn’t make you do it a certain way. The most modern way to handle identity Is called claims-based security. If you go with claims-based security, you will need to decide who your identity provider (IP) is. That could be a domain (via Active Directory), a social-web network provider (such as Google or Yahoo or Facebook), or your own custom security token service backed by a credentials database. If you want to support multiple identity providers (so users have a choice of how they sign in), you would want to leverage Windows Azure's Access Control Service as an intermediary. Make sure your IP(s) can provide the information you need to make good authorization decisions.

Regarding item 2 (security samples), I recommend trying out the hands-on labs in the [Windows Identity Developer Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14347). That will give you a good feel for what claims-based security is like.

Regarding item 3 (saving and retrieving file-oriented data) blob storage would be the logical service to use. You’ll need to provide an access layer and user interface in order to provide the security and sharing features you described.

Regarding item 4 (using Enterprise Library for Data Access on Windows Azure), [this article](http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/02/enterprise-library-on-windows-azure-key-learnings-from-customer-project) may be helpful.

Comment: Hi David - thanks for the comments. Problem is that this is a startup company and money is very short, so I cannot afford expert advice. I will want to use my own access provider if possible - I have a table called [Users] which contain UserID, CustomerID, Name, Email and Password. I will do some simple select to validate the credentials provided. I am not sure if this is an outdated way to do it? (Sounds like it would be best to ACS?). Great article on EntLib DAL :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to break this down to specific questions.

1. If you want the app to manage the userID password then MembershipServices is and option.  If you want to trust a third party for authentication then ACS.  Why is logon and session the same question.
2. more about security.  Start with requirements
3. Tables have a row size limit.  You have only small files?
   Shared Access Signiture will take load off the web site
4. You can only learn by video?  Come on there is lots of info out there.

Comment: Hi Blam - I am not sure what you mean about "why is logon and session the same question"? I guess what I meant was that userid+customerid will be stored in a session after authenticating the user through a simple user+pass webform.

Comment: For the security, we need it to be very tight since the customers will post highly sensitive documents in the cloud, so we need to take every measure we can to tighten the security.

The file sizes will typically be around 3-100 mb pdf files. I will look into this Shared Access Signature - I guess this is for restricting access to the files right?

:) I can also learn by reading docs, but my main problem is that the more information I get, the more confusing it becomes, because you can explore all sorts of different directions. My hope was that somebody could say "you need this and not that".

Comment: Shared Access Signature is for exactly what I stated - take load off the web site.  Still what are the requirements.   Does you app need to manage the userID and password or to you want to defer to a trusted authority?    If you are storing highly sensitive documents then you have a ways to go.  IMHO you are not even asking good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is fine, except I'd drop the "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(result, false);" line. In Azure you will seem to lose your UserData field value or have the appearance of the userData field not holding it's value.  In actuality your SetAuthCookie will create a 2nd version of your already established ticket.  I guess that might come in handy if you need to spawn off instances of your ticket to other processes.  In most applications a single version is all you need to run your cloud works for a single web role.  Also I've taken this approach and made use of the azure storage table to store additional data that I required, and I'm glad I did.  There are some strange occurrences in Azure where session variables, including this approach, just sometimes return null.  It's like streaming UDP vs TCP.  Internet is streaming.  one byte goes off, and the session seems to go away and back again in the next refresh, and thats on reason I added more assurances using Azure's table storage.  I'm creating session transactions there.  So far so good and very little table transacting equals peace of mind.